# My link is not working well using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

I have a link like this

```
 <li><a class='myclass' href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller">Search</a></li>
```

and my jquery is

```
 $("a.myclass").click(function(){
 var link  = $(this);
 var url = link.attr("href");
 $(".content").load(url); 

 return false; 

});
```

actually it links correctly the problem is my list in my menu looks ugly not it looks it should be though other li looks ok. when i change to

```
 <li><a class='.myclass.' href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller">Search</a></li>
```

it looks correctly but its not linking to anything.

What is the problem here?

Here is my css

```
 .webwidget_vertical_menu {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

    }
 .webwidget_vertical_menu ul{
    padding: 0.5px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}
.webwidget_vertical_menu li{


}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;

}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li a{
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li ul li{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    border:none;
}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li ul li ul{

}
.webwidget_vertical_menu_down_drop{
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
.webwidget_vertical_menu ul li li{
    font-weight: normal;
}


body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;

}

ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;  
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; 
}
a img { 
    border: none;
}

a:link {
    color:#414958;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
a:visited {
    color: #4E5869;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.header {
    background-color: #ADB96E;

}

.sidebar1 {

    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar2 {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; }

ul.nav {
    list-style: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #666; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
ul.nav li {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
     list-style: none;
     position:relative;
     }
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { 
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #C6D580;
    color: #000;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { 
    background: #ADB96E;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* ~~The footer ~~ */
.footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #CCC49F;
    position: relative;
    clear: both; 
}

/* ~~miscellaneous float/clear classes~~ */
.fltrt {  
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px; 
}
.menu {
    color: #414141;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:650; 
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: remove the extra `.` at the end of the class name.

Comment: Do you mean that your first example doesn't get the correct syntax highlighting in your IDE? If so, change the single quotes around `myclass` to double quotes.

Comment: What do you mean my "looks correct"? Why do you have `.`s before and after `myclass`?  What's the question?

Comment: If the issue is with how it's displayed, you'll want to include the relevant CSS declarations. An example that illustrates the problem would be great too.

Comment: but when remove the the looks my list is a mess

Comment: `myclass` isn't in your CSS file anywhere.  Show us more of the HTML, like the `ul`.

Comment: im using the webwidget_vertical_menu class sorry

Comment: <li><a href="#">User</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a class='webwidget_vertical_menu' href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller">Search for User</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the dot (.) in class name.

Try this:

```
<li><a class='myclass' href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller">Search</a></li>
```

And jquery...

```
// This means select the `<a>` element with class `myclass`. 
// Dot (.) means class selector.
$("a.myclass").click(function(){
    var link  = $(this);
    var url = link.attr("href");
    $(".content").load(url); 

    return false; 

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't have the dot at the front either...that's just for the selector, it's not part of the class name.

Comment: So your solution is for them to use the code they've said causes the display problem they're hoping to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I need more conditions to answer exactly, but I guess there are some css styles for `myclass`. Try to rename myclass to something like `f-ajax-link-selector` (don't forget to change it in JS) and try to refresh the page.

Comment: my css and my jquery has the same file name